# Android + POI Excel + add data in existing file

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to append the data in existing excel file, but nothing is written. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static void writeSheet(String data) {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook;

    try {
        String outFileName = "filebook.xls";

        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File outFile = new File(path, outFileName);
        workbook = (HSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(outFile);

        Row row = workbook.getSheetAt(0).createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("text");

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile,true);
        workbook.write(outputStream);

        outputStream.close();
        workbook.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: are uou creating a new file or updating inside existing file !

Answer (score 3):

Instead

```
File outFile = new File(path, outFileName);
workbook = (HSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(outFile);
```

Try with

```
FileInputStream outFile = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(outFile);
```

So your code

```
public static void writeSheet(String data) {
HSSFWorkbook workbook;

try {
    String outFileName = "filebook.xls";

    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path, outFileName))
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

    Row row = workbook.getSheetAt(0).createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("text");

    file.close();

    FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(path, outFileName));
    workbook.write(outFile);
    outFile.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create Excell file using java

```
File file = new File(filename);
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file,
                wbSettings);

        workbook.createSheet("My_excell_file", 0);
        WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
         WritableFont ledgerFont = new WritableFont(
        WritableFont.createFont("Arial"),
        WritableFont.DEFAULT_POINT_SIZE, WritableFont.BOLD, false,
        UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE, Colour.GRAY_80);
        Label labelhead1;
        Label labelhead2;
        Label labelhead3;
        private WritableCellFormat headFormat, langFormat;
        labelhead1 = new Label(0, 1, "KEY", this.headFormat);
        labelhead2 = new Label(1, 1, "VALUE", this.headFormat);
        labelhead3 = new Label(2, 1, "PROPERTY", this.headFormat);
        excelSheet.addCell(labelhead1);
        excelSheet.addCell(labelhead2);
        excelSheet.addCell(labelhead3);
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
        //           For Update
        HSSFRow row;
        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        cell = row.getCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Updated Values");
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but I am looking the information how to add the data to existing file ( I have the file and I have the data in it), without creating a new file and removing the existing data

Comment: @Delphian see updated answer to update your excell file.